# UV mapping and extra images

Tags: uv-image-editor

I keep making a smart UV map for one of my combined meshes and whenever I go into texture paint, it deletes the UV Map. When I into the imported images on the UV map it shows four of the same. I want to reduce my file size. How do I delete the extra imported images?

[image]

Comment: it's not very clear, maybe your UVs are overlapping? Please show some screenshots

Comment: please share the object: https://pasteall.org/blend/